# Getting my queries' results into a string so it can be printed

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I'm having a problem with the following:

I have the function process_query as below:

```
def process_query(query, parameters):

    print query

    print parameters

    if(parameters is None):

        cursor1.execute(query)

        return cursor1.fetchall()

    else:

        cursor1.execute(query, parameters)

        return cursor1.fetchall()
```

which I call in the following function:

```
def recieving_sumrpt():

    theList=[]

    theList=cursor1.execute('SELECT DISTINCT SSN FROM Employee').fetchall()  

    print theList

    templist=[['SSN','Lname','FName','MInit','Known Hours','Unknown hours','Overtime']]

    for i in theList:

        basics= process_query('SELECT SSN, LName, FName, MInit FROM Employee WHERE SSN=?', (i)) 

        templist.append(basics)

        known_hours = process_query('SELECT sum(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM  Works_On WHERE ESSN=?', (i))

        print templist, known_hours

        templist.append(known_hours[0])
        count=cursor1.execute('SELECT Distinct ESSN FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?', (i)).rowcount

        if count >=1:

            templist.append('Yes')

        else:
            templist.append('No')
```

the trouble is when I print templist I have the following appearance:

```
[['SSN', 'Lname', 'FName', 'MInit', 'Known Hours', 'Unknown hours', 'Overtime'],

 [('123456789', 'Smith', 'John', 'B')], [(Decimal('40.0'), )], 'No', 'Yes', 

[('333445555', 'Wong', 'Franklin', 'T')], [(Decimal('40.0'), )], 'No', 'Yes', 

[('453453453', 'English', 'Joyce', 'A')], [(Decimal('40.0'), )], 'No', 'Yes', 

[('666884444', 'Narayan', 'Ramesh', 'K')], [(Decimal('40.0'), )], 'No', 'Yes', 

[('888665555', 'Borg', 'James', 'E')], [(Decimal('0.0'), )], 'Yes', 'Yes', 

[('987654321', 'Wallace', 'Jennifer', 'S')], [(Decimal('35.0'), )], 'No', 'Yes', 

[('987987987', 'Jabbar', 'Ahmad', 'V')], [(Decimal('40.0'), )], 'No', 'Yes', 

[('999887777', 'Zelaya', 'Alicia', 'J')], [(Decimal('40.0'), )], 'No', 'Yes']
```

Which I believe causes problems later when I want to print out my results:

```
def printing(list):

    for i in list:

        print '%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-15s %-10s %-15s' % (i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4], i[5], i[6])
```

as this gives the error: "list index out of range"

which I believe stems from the fact that I do not have the following apperance:

```
['999887777', 'Zelaya', 'Alicia', 'J', Decimal('40.0'), 'No', 'Yes']
```

For each row. (Could be wrong though, this is my first python lab).

The output of the printing function is merely:

```
SSN        Lname      FName      MInit      Known Hours     Unknown hours Overtime
```

And nothing more.

How can I make all this into something that can be printed? And is it possible for the decimal('40.0') appearance in the list to be removed? I've tried using append(float(known_hours[0]) but this gave me an error saying that known_hours must be a number or a string. Also, I haven't really figured out how to print yet; is there any problem with that function, or the process_query function as I have configured it quite a lot from the original, given, function?

Comment: May I suggest you to  edit your post to provide *only* a [SSCC example](http://sscce.org) that focus on *this* particular issue. Is a about "fetching rows" or extracting data from a Python list?

Comment: I will look into that. I think that the problem is that I get a string which is not really a string because it involves tuples etc. 

The reason I have so much in is so that I can get some help to:
Get it into a valid string (hence the loop where I build templist) so I can print it with the printing function. process_query is in because I've had several issues regarding how to process and I am not 100 % sure that this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = [['SSN', 'Lname', 'FName', 'MInit', 'Known Hours', 'Unknown hours', 'Overtime'],
        [('123456789', 'Smith', 'John', 'B')],
        [(Decimal('40.0'), )],
        'No',
        'Yes', 
        [('333445555', 'Wong', 'Franklin', 'T')], 
        [(Decimal('40.0'), )]
]

def printing(list):

    for i in list:

        print '%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-15s %-10s %-15s' % (i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4], i[5], i[6])
```

It is most evident that the list items don't have 7 entries...
As a matter of fact, while formatting properly the data you could see the content of the list is not even consistent. There are lists, list of tuples, stings, etc...

---

I will try to put you on the right track to clean-up the mess:

```
def recieving_sumrpt():
    theList = cursor1.execute('SELECT DISTINCT SSN FROM Employee').fetchall()  
    # You get a list of tupple containing each one SSN

    templist=[['SSN','Lname','FName','MInit','Known Hours','Unknown hours','Overtime']]
    # ok: a list of list of 7 strings.

    for i in theList: # for each SSN
        # here i contains a tuple of *1* element
        basics= process_query('SELECT SSN, LName, FName, MInit FROM Employee WHERE SSN=?', i) 
        # basics contains now a list on *one* tupple of *4* items

        templist.append(basics)

    ...
```

As you will see in the above comments, at this point, I think you are already on the *wrong* track. My *guess* is you want consistent list. Either with 4 or 7 items since you intend to display the result as some kind of table.

A last word: maybe the main difficulty here is that you didn't understand that fetch all return a "list of tupple". Each item in the list for each *row*. An the tuple contain one item for each column. As an example, while querying the SSN, you should obtain something like that:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
^ ^     
 \ \ each "row" is a tuple of 1 item because I selected only one *column*
  \
   \ a list of 3 items because there was 3 rows in my test table
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!

I might not have been clear enough. I am aware of that and the problem is  how to convert it into a string without any tuples etc. so I can use my printing function to print it out.

Comment: @GustavDanell I have edited my answer with some info that could help you to find yourself (most of) the problem(s) ;)

Comment: @GustavDanell As a final advice: code comments, "print" statements and meaningful code formatting *are* your best friends for life!

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not understand that fetchall returns tuples of data so I guess most of the problems arises from there.

Do you have any idea how to do this in another matter?

I've tried to use a while loop with the fetchone statement which I believe will clear out the issue of unwanted tuples? However I did got errors of my len(rows) which I used to see if I needed to loop over several rows in order to make every one into the list but it complained about row being a NoneType and thus doesn't have any length.

Comment: @Sylvian Leroux that is true. I tend to complete the assignment before I lay back and add the finishing touches with appearence, trimming the code and comments merely because I tend to get so many errors mean-while I program that it only takes additional time. =)